# Switch desktop without sign out

Tags: desktop-environments

I have multiple desktop environments installed, like kubuntu-desktop, lubuntu-desktop. Also I need to switch between these desktops frequently. So is there any possible way that I don't need to log out and log back in to switch my desktop from gnome to kubuntu?

Comment: You could create a second user, choose another tty by typing CTRL - ALT - Fn and start X. I think it is possible to configure your display manager to show its login screen on that second tty, but I have never tried.

Comment: Could you explain why you "*need to switch between these desktops frequently*"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe it will help you: I'm currently running KDE but have LXDE installed, and I managed to launch LXDE panel and some services with just typing `startlxde` command. However, this doesn't close KDE's panels, so I would have to kill them manually (with `killall plasma-desktop` or so).

I also managed to launch RazorQt with `startrazor`.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure whether all DEs provide such bootstrap commands. Xfce4, for example, provides `startxfce4`, but it can't be run within an existing X session.

Anyway, I think you don't need to run the whole DE. Try starting just window manager and desktop, e.g. `kwin --replace` and `plasma-desktop` for KDE.

P.S. Kubuntu is not a DE. KDE is a DE. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`dm-tool` is a tool to communicate with the LightDM display manager.

- Run: `$ dm-tool add-nested-seat`
- Next login using any desktop environment
- To run in full screen `Xephyr :1 -br -fullscreen & dm-tool add-local-x-seat 1`